Repeat \maketitle with exactly the same style and parameters
I am trying to create a document that will, at some arbitrary point, repeat the title from the front page.
\documentclass[a4paper,anonymous]{lipics-v2021}

\title{My Paper}

\titlerunning{paper} 

\author{Me}{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

% Generate title
\maketitle

% Any amount of text/sections
lorem ipsum...

% I now want to show exactly the same title again
\maketitle

\end{document}

This code, however, outputs completely unformatted text of the title and author parameters given above.
A few links [1,2] suggest using the titling package, although there are two issues here:

I Can't seem to get it to use the \maketitle as defined in the .cls file for my project (lipics, in my case)
The titling package requires me to repeat all of parameters for \maketitle. (e.g. \title{..}, \author{}, etc.).


In your class, as well as in standard classes, the \maketitle disables itself, and also empties the \@title and \@author macros comtaining the metadata definined by the comnands \title{...} and \author{...}
(See lines 304 and followings on [github's lipic-v2021 class][1]).
Hence you could \renewcomnand (in the preamble) the \maketitle comnand with the same code (starting on line 287) except the lines 304 to 314.
A standard WARNING:you can do that for personal use. But never do this kind of changes if your document is intended for submission to the correspomding journal/conference/editor (here to LIPIcs series conferences).
[1]: https://github.com/prosysscience/lipics/blob/master/lipics-v2021.cls

Sorry, I saw your answer when I validate mine, which is essentially the same, but provides a bit more details.

Thank you - this worked perfectly. This is intended for submission to a publication - why do you advise against it in such cases?

It will likely break their workflow or formating rules. In lipic gude one reads: //  Generally speaking, please do not override thelipics-v2021-style defaults. To be more specif i c, a short checklist also used by Dagstuhl Publishing during the f i nal typesetting is given below. In case of non-compliance with these rules Dagstuhl Publishing will remove the corresponding parts of L ATEX code and replace it with thelipics-v2021defaults.
In serious cases, we may reject the LaTeX-source and expect the corresponding author to revise the relevant parts.

Looking at the class definition, you'll find (lines 287-315)
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}

The second \maketitle fails because of all \global\let...\relax and \global\let...\@empty.
You can try to redefine it (inside \makeatletter and \makeatother to handle the character @ in macro names).
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

The full title page, including the footer, is printed again. If you want only the title itself, you have to look at \@maketitle definition, and copy the parts you needs.
Example:
\documentclass[a4paper,anonymous]{lipics-v2021}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\maketitle{\par
  \begingroup
    \thispagestyle{plain}
    \renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}%
    \if@twocolumn
      \ifnum \col@number=\@ne
        \@maketitle
      \else
        \twocolumn[\@maketitle]%
      \fi
    \else
      \newpage
      \global\@topnum\z@   % Prevents figures from going at top of page.
      \@maketitle
    \fi
    \thispagestyle{plain}\@thanks
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\title{My Paper}

\titlerunning{paper}

\author{Me}{}{}{}{}

\begin{document}

% Generate title
\maketitle

% Any amount of text/sections
lorem ipsum...

% I now want to show exactly the same title again
\maketitle

\end{document}


This worked exactly as I wanted, thank you. It must have been a coincidence when I tried it with other .sty files. I've removed that claim from my post.

@sxt643 .sty files are for packages. I thinks you means .cls files, which are for classes (article or here lipics-v2021).
